# getting mean of variables based on names

Tags: r, names

I have a vector like this `hu <-rnorm(20)` with names like this `names(hu) <- c(1:5,1:5,6:10,3:7)` how to group them so I can take the means based on names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
 tapply(hu, names(hu), FUN=mean)
```

If you need in the order 1:10, convert the names(hu) from 'character' to 'numeric'

```
 tapply(hu, as.numeric(names(hu)), FUN=mean)
```

Or

```
  unique(ave(hu, names(hu)))
```